# laravel 6 calling post route to return to the same page for sorting table

Tags: laravel, sorting, post, get

I am trying to create a table which the user can sort

I created the following two routes

```
 route::get('/manager', 'Manager\DeadlineController@index')->middleware(['auth', 'auth.manager'])->name('manager.index');
    route::post('/manager/{name_id}', 'Manager\DeadlineController@sortByName')->middleware(['auth', 'auth.manager'])->name('manager.sortByName');
```

from my php artisan route:list

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | manager                      | manager.index        | App\Http\Controllers\Manager\DeadlineController@index                  | web,auth,auth.manager |
|        | POST      | manager/{name_id}            | manager.sortByName   | App\Http\Controllers\Manager\DeadlineController@sortByName             | web,auth,auth.manager |
```

and set up my controller as follows

```
public function index()
{
    return view('deadline.index')
    ->with([
        'modules' => Module::all(),
        'name_id' => 0
    ]);
}

public function sortByName($name_id){
    if($name_id == 0){
        $sortedModule = Module::orderBy('name', 'DESC')->get();
    }
    else{
        $sortedModule = Module::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
    }

    return view('deadline.index')
    ->with([
        'modules' => $sortedModule,
        'name_id' => 1
    ]);
}
```

in my view i use the following link to sort

```
 <th scope="col"><a href="{{ route('manager.sortByName', $name_id) }}">NAME</a></th>
```

but when i use this link in my view I am somehow redirected to my GET route because i get the following error

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? Any help or tips will be appreciated. Please ask if I need to provide more details

### Update

I change the link in my view to a form tag with a submit button and now it works

```
<th scope="col">
   <form action="{{ route('manager.sortByName', $name_id) }}" method="POST">
         @csrf
         <button type="submit">NAAM</button>
    </form>
</th>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on `<a>` tag it does GET request, so you need to change your route from POST to GET, also returning view as a response to post method is not good idea,the best solution is GET route

Comment: Well I changed the a tag to a form tag and now it works. Why is returning a view as a response to a POST method  a bad idea?

Comment: just try to refresh the page and you'll see the alert, if you accept sending data one more time, that will cause your form to be submitted twice, so if you have something like payment or send mail, it'll run twice on refresh. You have to avoid this